# how to determine the origin of: one core to be at 100% and "freeze" the machine?

Tags: io, freeze

Sometimes after I turn on the desktop PC, randomly one of the 4 cores goes to 100% and the machine "freezes".

Well, I have `htop` running on it from a remote connection and I can see that all processes are still working.

An interesting thing that happens is ex.: a youtube video will continue playing its audio but the screen becomes all frozen, even the mouse won't change its position.

At the top of the list at htop, this time was kworker with 100% cpu usage, but other times there was no process at 100%. The cpu 1 (core index 0) was at 100%. So, the core 0 was being actively used by about 10% and the remaining bar was all red, filling 'til 100%. I think that red filling indicator is IO wait right?

Then the load average will not stop increasing.

So I guess it is related to some kind of IO, I would guess video IO? What commands I could use to test it?

In this case, I can't even create a new remote connection, it won't accept, will just freeze the attempt. So I will start such command on a loop and monitor its output whenever the next freeze happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is probably video io. Because there is a kworker on 100%, there is also an interrupt overflow.

Interrupts are handled on linux in two steps: 1) the direct interrupt handler collects all of the interrupt data in a temporary queue 2) the workers are working not in the interrupt handlers, but as separate kernel threads. They are essentially processes - but without a user space, they run entirely in kernel.

Is has being so, because the interrupt handlers... interrupt. It can happen any times, ignoring any locks, etc. Thus, they should do as few complex data structure handling, as it is possible. The problem is similar as you can call only a few functions from a user space signal handler. Thus, they collect the interruot data in a queue and then the workers process these queue, already out of the kernel space.

Now the problem is that video chips don't interrupt too much, the task of the video drivers is only to set up a the vga settings and to produce a mapped buffer to screen. They shouldn't interrupt too many, but despite that it happens a lot.

The youtube audio doesn't stop because it is a multithreaded thing and its audio processing thread doesn't even know that the video player is hanged.

What is in your dmesg?

I suspect buggy vga hardware or a driver problem.

Comment: I think my hardware may be buggy then, I will put a dmesg in a loop to see what happens, may freeze tomorrow again, that is quite random too. I guess I shuld filter dmesg for critical, crash, error etc right?

Comment: @AquariusPower The dmesg is the kernel log, although it is collected by the system logging daemons, it has also an internal buffer in the kernel (by default its size is 64k). To get exact, unfiltered output, simply execute the dmesg command. If only you video is frozen, you should probably be able to ssh your system from local network (if you have), and execute the dmedg there. If you don't have a local network, you have to reboot and check the logs.

Comment: I changed my video card (that finally died, R.I.Pieces card...), around 11/2017, and since then I havent had that problem, so I will accept this one, thx!

Comment: @AquariusPower My pleasure :-) Btw, nvidia cards are notoriously evil on Linux, because they come mostly with the binary driver of the nvidia. No source code -> no community bugfixes. There is also a slower, but much more stable opensource driver, it is better for everything except 3d gaming, named nouveau. If you can, use that.